# How to upload files to azure blob container folders with Node RED

Tags: npm, blob, node-red, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

My use case is to upload files to Azure Blob container.

My azure blob container having a folder "Images". I need to upload my files into the folder "Images" in blob container.

Using [https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-azure-blob-storage 1] node I can upload files into container root folder. How to save files in "Images" folder using node red?

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blob service is based on a flat storage scheme, not a hierarchical scheme. it does not  `directory`. However, you may specify a string delimiter within a blob name to define a virtual hierarchy. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names).

So you want to upload into the folder "Images" in blob container, you can define blob name `Images/{filename}`. For example

[image]
[image]